# where to initialize schedule.yml file for sidekiq scheduler

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scheduled-tasks, sidekiq

I have a config/schedule.yml file which has cron for recurring jobs in my app. But I am not sure where/how to initialize that file? In Resque we used to initialize it in resque.rake file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sidekiq is not really made for recurring jobs. Quoting from the [sidekiq github wiki page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs):

> For recurring tasks, I recommend using the clockwork or whenever gems which integrate with your system's cron to schedule tasks.

I have not used sidekiq (but other similar tools like delayed_job and pure ruby schedulers like rufus_scheduler) but a major problem with non-cron based tools is to guarantee the recurring jobs will actually be executed and only the number of times you desired to. In an typical production environment with passenger it can easily happen for all ruby process to cease (thus no execution at all) or twenty processes all trying to execute the same job.

We long switched to [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for which it is fun writing recurring jobs and which takes care of all the hassels in adding cronjobs to your system.

If you really want a easier solution and have no need for reliable execution [rufus_scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) is an option

Comment: Please note cronjobs/whenever will start up a new rails env upon execution, this can be unafforadble in many prod systems.

Comment: This is true if you use for instance the whenever runner (which can use a rails model directly). This convenience of course comes with the overhead of loading a rails environment (how otherwise would the model know of all the stuff surrounding it :).

In general for recurring tasks which have to be executed more often you can write rake tasks or even simple shell scripts which are added to your whenever config. I think if you are triggering jobs more than a couple times per hour cron is not the place for it. For the original question there now exists the sidetiq gem which is a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

In late 2018, there are options for cron-like (aka "periodic") job scheduling with Sidekiq.

The easiest option would be to pay for Sidekiq Enterprise which provides official support for this functionality. A cheaper option is to install https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron which (as writing) is actively maintained and has over four million downloads.